# MongoDB update (add field to nearly every document) is very very slow

Tags: mongodb, save, updates

I am working on a MongoDB cluster.

One DB named `bnccdb`, with a collection named `AnalysedLiterature`. It has about 7,000,000 documents in it.

For each document, I want to add two keys and then update this document.

I am using Java client. So I query this document, add these both keys to the `BasicDBObject` and then I use the `save()` method to update this object. I found the speed is so slow that it will take me nearly several weeks to complete the update for this whole collection.

I wonder the reason why my update operation is so slow is that what I do is add keys.

This will cause a disk/block re-arrangement in the background, so this operation becomes extremely time-consuming.

After I changed from save() to update, problem remains.This is my status information.
[image]
[image]

From the output of mongostat,it is very obvious that the faults rate is absolutely high.But I don't know what cased it.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: It is possible that adding the two keys could be causing the update operation to move every single document. One way to tell is by the rapid increase in size for one but also tools such as mongostat should tell you

Comment: Are you using _id to query the document? If not is the field you are using indexed? If the issue is on disk moves then you could try padding your documents on insertion with space you plan to use. You could then remove and add your keys without increasing size on the update.

Comment: @Sammaye I have updated my question with two pictures.It show that the faults from mongstat command is very high ,but I don't know what caused it.Can you please help me?